# Polymer POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: firebase, polymer, stripe-payments, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a charge for [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) using node.js. So I have followed [Firebase method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) to see if I could get this working:

For clarity, I have left out the polymer elements imports. Assume all is well.

**/charge.html:**

```
<dom-module id="stripe-charge">
  <template>
    <script>
      var firebaseStripe = new Firebase('https://blahblah.firebaseio-demo.com/');

        firebaseStripe.set({
          var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_blahblah");
          var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

          var charge = stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
            currency: "gbp",
            source: stripeToken,
            description: "Example charge"
          }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
              // The card has been declined
            }
        });
    </script>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'stripe-charge',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**index:**

```
<section data-route="charge">
 <stripe-charge></stripe-charge>
</section>
```

**routing.html:**

```
page('/charge', function () {
  app.route = 'charge';
});

page({
  hashbang: true
});
```

**form:**

```
<form is="iron-form" id="myForm" action="http://localhost:3000/#!/charge" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" is="iron-input" id="amount" name="amount" bind-value="{{total}}">
   <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken"/>
   <input type="hidden" is="iron-input" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" bind-value="{{emailInput}}"/>
</form>
<paper-button class="fullBtn" id="customButton" on-click="stripe">
  <iron-icon icon="icons:credit-card"></iron-icon>
  Pay
</paper-button>
```

When I press the pay button, fill out card details etc, then hit the Strip pay button, I get the green but when it goes to the charge page, I get `POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)` Somehow it's not going to the page. Any ideas? I feel there will be more errors but for now, I want to get that page. Firebase issue?

Comment: Not sure how in any universe a 404 on localhost:3000 could be a Firebase issue. Almost certainly the redirect URL for Stripe is incorrect.

Comment: That is why I ask the question.

Comment: Start by reducing the problem set to the [minimum viable code that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll probably encounter the same conditions if you remove the Firebase code and just send the Stripe request directly, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your url be a true path, not a hash location:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="myForm" action="http://localhost:3000/charge" method="post">
```

You need to run a server that accepts the post and then makes a call to Stripe with your private key, you cannot run Stripe as a pure client-only process.

The first step in the browser calls stripe and packages up the supplied credit card information, but then you need to provide that token to your server. Otherwise anyone could submit charges on your behalf, including refunds!

Comment: The browser URL now goes to `http://localhost:3000/charge` and page displays `Cannot POST /charge`

Comment: you need to have a server running that will do the post to stripe